# how do you wait for data to load before view in angular 2

Tags: angular, asynchronous, loading

**Component:**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  tridentData: TridentData;

  constructor(private tridentServices: TridentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tridentServices.getTridentData()
                    .subscribe(
                      (data: TridentData) => {
                        this.tridentData = data;
                      }
                    )
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1>{{ tridentData }}</h1>   <---results in undefined
```

**The Problem:**

I am calling `getTridentData()` (A `GET` request, that returns json) on my `tridentData` object. I am having a ASYNC problem where the view loads before my `tridentData` object can retrieve the data the db. This results tridentData in undefined and my whole page breaks. How do I implement a loading animation and have the view wait for the data to load before popping in?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: You can use `*ngIf="data"` in your components template or a guard to make the router wait before adding the component until the data becomes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your template you can add a condition to the h1 tag :

```
<h1 *ngIf="tridentData">{{ tridentData }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

We'd need to see your getTridentData() code to be sure but really what you probably want to do is use the async pipe.

`{{ tridentData | async }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
      showTridentData:Promise<boolean>;

      ngOnInit() {
        this.tridentServices.getTridentData()
                        .subscribe(
                          (data: TridentData) => {
                            this.tridentData = data;
                            this.showTridentData=Promise.resolve(true);
                          }
                        );
      }
```

in your HTML use as this

```
 <h1 *ngIf="showTridentData | async">{{tridentData}}</h1>
```